# Listing of All Standard Profiles and their Metadata API Names

Tags: metadata-api, profile

What is a listing of all Salesforce standard profiles as they relate to the Metadata API?  The names do not match the user interface in Salesforce.

---

When performing a bulkRetrieve of all profiles in a new developer organization, the files retrieved do not match those of the standard profiles.

Example target for ant:

```
 <target name="bulkRetrieveProfile">
    <sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" metadataType="Profile" retrieveTarget="${sf.dir}" batchSize="${sf.batchsize}"/>
   </target>
```

When pulled, only standard profiles are listed, with the exception of three custom profiles that Salesforce makes.  System Administrator will not be listed in the directory pulled, which is a standard profile.

Example output when performing a FINDSTR on the directory of the bulkRetrieves (note System Administrator, as the Salesforce UI lists, is not included):

[image: Output of standard profiles]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a listing of all standard profiles and their license key definition and their corresponding metadata API Name, when performing a retrieve:

[image: Standard Profiles]

Unfortunately SFSE does not have markdown for tables so I have added as a picture to preserve formatting.

[Developer documentation for metadata API and profiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm)

[SOAP API documentation for User License Key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm)

Answer (score 1):

We can find the API name(FullName) of Profile using **Tooling** query, eg:

```
SELECT Id, Name, FullName FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'
```

Some std profiles:

```
Standard User: Standard
Contract Manager
Marketing User: MarketingProfile
Solution Manager: SolutionManager
System Administrator: Admin
```